# Polymorphism without methods in go

Tags: go, polymorphism

Note: I'm editing this question to a concrete example of why I want to do this, which is why some of the answers might no longer make sense in context.

I am writing a bit of code that passes data from an input. The data is in the form of tags that have an identifier of what kind of data they contain and then the data.

Unfortunately I have no control over the input and don't know in advance what tags will be in it, one might be an int another might be a string, yet another might be an array of ints.

The problem arises when I need to handle all tags like the same type, for instance if I have a slice of tags, of a function that either accepts or returns a tag.

The solutions I have so far seen to this is to define the slices/functions with an empty interface which would allow me to do so, however that is kinda undesirable as it would not tell anything to other people using the package about what types are expected and also kinda defies the point of having a typed language in the first place.

Interfaces does however seem to be the solution here, and i would love to have a `Tag` interface to pass around, that does require though that I define methods on them, and there are really no methods they need.

My current solution looks like this

```golang
type Tag interface{
    implementTag()
}

type TagInt int
func (tag TagInt) implementTag() {}

type TagString string
func (tag TagInt) implementTag() {}
```

While this does indeed work and solves my problem, having to define dummy methods just for that feels very wrong.

So my question sums up in this: Are there any way that I can define that something is a `Tag` without having to define dummy methods?

Comment: By using the empty interface.

Comment: That would require me to define any function that took one of those as its first argument with an empty interface as its type. I guess I can do that but then I would just rather go with the sollution I posted and retain some control over what is passed in.

Comment: Why are you asking? Why do you want to use a strictly typed language for that?

Comment: Short version: I'm loading a bunch of tags in that can be of different types (I have no control over the input) but I still want to be able to say that "this is a list of tags" or "this method returns a tag" or "this method requires a tag"

Answer (score 3):

> And now want to make a slice that can hold both t1 and t2 but nothing else.

You cannot do that. Sorry.

Comment: Assuming you comment on that specific line. I can do that. That is the use of interfaces. Question is if I can do it without having to define dummy methods.

Comment: @Zlug no, you literally can't. Interface implementation is implicit in Go, so anyone could create a type that fulfills the interface and it could be inserted in that slice. You *cannot* restrict a slice to two specific types.

Comment: I see I have chosen the wrong words then. I am perfectly okay with any other value that fulfills the interface being used.
What I'm looking fore is a way to make a type fulfill an interface without having to define a method. Or if another way than interfaces solves this issue I'm totally okay with that too.

Comment: *"What I'm looking fore is a way to make a type fulfill an interface without having to define a method."* @Zlug You can do this only with struct types and not with ints, strings, etc. You can do it by implementing the method once on type `x` and then have the other *struct* types embed `x`.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in your scenario is accept any type in the parameters with an empty interface then use a type assertion inside to confirm that it's the type that you want.

```
if t1, ok := interfaceInput.(t1); !ok{
    // handle it being the wrong type here
    return
}
```

Also if you want the tight coupling between a data type and it's method, namely an object, what's so wrong with having it be a method of the object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]interface{}` for a "slice of any type" but then it's up to you to use type assertions and/or type switches to discover the actual runtime types of that slice's members.

Learn more about empty interfaces in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14)

---

> And now want to make a slice that can hold both t1 and t2 but nothing
>   else.

This is quite an unusual requirement and you're unlikely to need this in Go. But you could also do your own discriminated union with:

```
type item struct {
  typeSelector int
  t1Value t1
  t2Value t2
}
```

And then use `[]item`, checking `typeSelector` at runtime to see which value is populated.

Alternatively you could even use `*t1` and `*t2` and have `nil` signify "no value in this field".

Comment: Perhaps a better exampel would be if I want to make a function that takes an first argument that is eather of those two, but no other type.

Comment: You can't do that either, for the exact same reason you can't do that with a slice.

Comment: @Zlug: again, you'd have to use one of the methods outlined here. There is no other way, currently, to do that. That said, it's almost certain that interfaces should help you once you reconsider a more Go-idiomatic design

Comment: *"I want to make a function that takes an first argument that is eather of those two, but no other type."* @Zlug you can kind of fake this by having the interface and the two types live in their own package, export the interface type but keep its methods unexported, then no type outside of that package will be able to implement that interface. Only the types the live in the same package as that interface will be able to implement it.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes. That is excately what I did in my example. I just hoped that I didn't didn't have to go there.
Thank's for the suggestion though.